# How to correct PWM signal

Tags: pwm, conductivity

I am trying to design something to test the electrical conductivity (EC) of water. Knowing that conductivity is the inverse of resistivity, my plan was to measure the resistance of the water via a conductivity probe and using Ohm's Law, then invert it for the conductivity.

As the probe needs an AC signal to work correctly, I am using a PWM signal direct from a microcontroller which then feeds a resistor, then the conductivity probe, much like a voltage divider. The other end of the probe is sat at 1/2 VCC to enable a +/- voltage swing across the probe.

The circuit is relatively simple and looks a bit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz2QA7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tested the circuit by plugging a fixed resistor in place of the probe. I have managed to get temperature compensation working properly, and I have calibration working by calibrating 2 points using a fixed resistor and I then get the results expected with various resistors.

When I attach a probe, I started to get incorrect readings. I suspected because the temperature compensation is not linear (I used a fixed 2%/°C) this would be the issue. After checking the temperature read by the probe, this was found not to be the case.

I attached an oscilloscope to one side of the probe to see what was happening. I has a 1413µS calibration solution, so I used a resistance box to give myself a resistor value of 707.714 Ohms. When fed into the circuit, my LCD read 1.41mS as expected. The oscilloscope waveform looked like this:

[image]

This is pretty much exactly what I was expecting. I then attached the probe, used some of the calibration solution. The LCD gave me a result of 1.32mS, which is incorrect, so I checked the oscilloscope. The result was this:

[image]

Here, the signal seems to not stabilise, but instead continue increasing until the negative edge. I am guessing this is my issue as I take multiple readings during the positive part of the PWM and average the result.

What could be causing the strange shape of the signal? And is there any way to stop it?

I have tried using a different probe, the same thing happens. I have added low value capacitors (few 10s of pF) across the probe and on one side to see if this makes any difference, this just gives me a distorted signal which is useless. I have even removed the input filter capacitor and this made no difference either. Any assistance is appreciated!

Extra info -

- PWM is 1kHz
- Op-amp is TLV9102
- When measuring, I wait for the PWM positive edge, wait 100µs for it to settle and take as many readings as possible before the negative edge, then average the result. This method works well with resistors.

**EDIT**

A thought I have had is perhaps the build up of ions before the polarity change is the reason for this shape?

Comment: This looks kind of logical – you're charging the capacitor with your opamp.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited the post probably just before your comment so you may not have seen it, but I had previously removed the capacitor to see if it made a difference and the shape is still the same. If it was just charging the capacitor, I would have expected a steady rise the entire wave, rather than shoot up to a certain point, then start to slowly rise. Also, if it was just charging the capacitor, why would it work fine with a resistor, but not with a probe in a solution?

Comment: Both positive and negative tops have a slope. I couldn't see if both have the same slope. But anyway, did you take the negative edges into account when averaging? Because if you run averaging only on positive side you can get wrong results. The slope on negative tops might compensate.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The negative does have a slight slope, but it is not the same. I don't take the negative into account normally, but I have done while testing this and it doesn't compensate for it

Comment: +1 on correct usage of s versus S. Not every day you see that.

Comment: @winny all the way through this project I have had people getting it incorrect!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for the reply. It's a simple setup. I'm not looking for ultra accuracy. I'm displaying in 0.01 resolution in mS only with a +/- 0.1mS accuracy. I don't have the equipment or budget for much else. I'm already forced to use a cheap electrode just to stay within budget

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I'm quite happy with the circuitry. I am coming round to the idea more that it is the ion build up on the electrode during the measurements, which would be an answer, so the question is answerable for sure.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Maybe my wording wasn't correct. I wasn't under the assumption it would be exactly the same and would in no way think it would act as an ideal resistor. That was a test to ensure I was able to get readings and do my conversions correctly. The question is what is causing the shape of the waveform. That can be answered with the current information I am sure.

Comment: I would suspect some kind of chemical action going on. What if you increase the PWM frequency (100kHZ); what if you decrease it (1Hz); does either one cause it to be stable?

Comment: @user253751 Todays job is experimenting with the PWM to see if this helps

Comment: @winny "s" is used for "second" and "S" is used for "Siemens" conductivity, in EU...

Comment: > "What could be causing the strange shape of the signal? And is there any way to stop it?" Chemical "adaptation"? Try with a (very) lower PWM frequency to see all "phenomena"... if it derives more ...

Comment: @Antonio51 That goes in the entire world of SI, but many people mix them up.

Comment: @Antonio51 I believe winny already knows that, hence his comment. I have changed the frequency and it is more apparent at lower frequencies, less so at higher frequencies so I am leaning towards a build up of ions on the sensor, so this would be more suited to chemistry if this is the case

Comment: Ok. :-)  ... Build up of ions on the sensors or simply ...  low "speed" of displacement of these ions. Can be this useful ? https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5090765

Comment: And perhaps this https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/08%3A_Solutions/8.10%3A_Ions_and_Electrolytes/8.10.9D%3A_8.10.9D%3A_Ionic_migration

Comment: Will look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let’s factor this into more manageable problems:

1. Measuring idealized resistive conductance.
2. Measuring conductance of a ionic fluid.

The former is a simple problem and you are assuming that the two are equivalent. That may be true to an extent, let’s first ensure you can measure the “spherical cow” idealized conductance of just a resistor.

Instead of electrodes use a resistors as conductance standards and get it to work. It’s then easy for us to help with that, since you can furnish schematics, pictures of your circuit and cabling, details of materials used (eg. the P/N for coax cable used), etc.

Once that’s solved, you can then head on to chemistry stack exchange to ask how close is actual water with electrodes in it to a bulk conductor with real-valued impedance. I’m afraid that the general answer is “not very”.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question asked. As you know, using resistors works fine. I think I may go over to chemistry to ask the question of what is causing the shape of that PWM signal as that is what I am trying to get answered. And no, I won't be able to post schematics as my employers won't allow it, hence drawing just a simplified section of it in the question.

Comment: Be aware of electrolysis occurring on probe surfaces. AC is often used to overcome this.